# Change the consecutive value of selected rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to update the value of the column matching the selection criteria and repeat it some consecutive times.
eg:

INPUT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [True,False,False,False,False,True,False,False]})
```

roll value to next 3 indexes
([input format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKRrw.png))

OUTPUT:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [True,True,True, False, False, True, True, True]}
```

([output format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mhPZ.png))

I looked at pandas.series.repeat but that adds new value. I need to make sure that the size remains the same.

Comment: the output has more values than input. please fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.rolling(...)` to get rolling window:

```py
df.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).agg(lambda x: any(x)).astype("bool")
```

Output:

```py
       a
0   True
1   True
2   True
3  False
4  False
5   True
6   True
7   True
```

Comment: what does any(x) does in this case? 
and also does .astype("bool") does?

Comment: ```any(x)``` is Boolean-function returning ```True```, if there's at least one ```True``` in the window. Then ```.astype("bool")``` casts outcome to Boolean, because otherwise it's auto-casting outcome of ```.agg(...)``` to ```float```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while and for loop like so:

```
i = 0 // index
content = 'true' // set content to replace

while (i < 3): // run 3 times
    for x in dataframe:
        dataframe['column'] = dataframe['column'].replace(content, str(i)) // replace content at index i
        i = i + 1 // add 1 to index
```

This way you replace values at a certain index while only looping through the first 3 indexes.